# Parity wallet stuck in addressbook

Tags: wallets, parity

I transferred eth to my parity account and then to my parity wallet. I accidentally erased the account, and it also erased my wallet. I got them back, but now my wallet is stuck in my addressbook. I can't make any transfers out, but I can transfer eth into the wallet. I've tried to add my wallet to the account tab, and it shows that it accepts it...but still doesn't show up on my accounts page. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reimport your accounts first into your Parity Wallet.

The wallet you created will stay as long in the address book as long as there are no keys for at least one of the owners available.